# Page not found error. Is Request URL wrong?

Tags: python, html, django

I got an error,Page not found.
In profile.html,I wrote

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html lang="ja">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>UPLOAD</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="registration/accounts/fashion_result.html">
      <input type="submit" value="ResultShow">
    </form>

    <div class="container">
      <form action="{% url 'accounts:upload_save' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ p_id }}" name="p_id">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

In this part

```
<form action="registration/accounts/fashion_result.html">
          <input type="submit" value="ResultShow">
 </form>
```

I wanna do screen transition(If I put this button,I wanna see fashion_result.html in browser.

But now,I got the error.
How can I fix this?

Furthermore,I added into urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/fashionresults/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/accounts/fashion_result.html'), name='fashionresults'

)
```

in profile.html

```
 <form action="registration/accounts/fashion_result.html">ResultShow</form>
```

(in the directory, there is fashion_result.html)

Comment: Do you having a url matching `registration/accounts/fashion_result.html` in you urls.py

Comment: share your urls.py

Comment: if you want to open a template only means use TemplateView and put <a href = "url" >button name</a> instaed of form.

Answer (score 2):

User TemplateView for resolve this issue

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/test/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='todo/index.html'), name="test"),
)
```

in html page

```
<a href="{% url 'test' %}" >ResultShow</a>
```

Comment: thx, ur comments.I wrote ur codes, so a link tag was showed.But if I put it, nothing was reload.What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:-

template-

```
<form action="/fashion_result">
          <input type="submit" value="ResultShow">
 </form>
```

urls.py:-

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from webpage import views
# from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.home),
    url(r'^fashion_result/$',views.fashionResult),
```

views.py-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def fashionResult(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/fashion_result.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where is the file located if it is in the same folder just use

```
<form action="fashion_result.html">
```

or else do one thing
"Shift + right click" on file then "copy as path"

come back and paste in "form action" absolutely that works.

Comment: thx, ur comments.I wrote ur codes,but only words was showed and I could not put anything.(So,the html file was not showed)What should I do?

Comment: Copy and paste that link in your form action. (form action=" Paste here ")